# Get values of duplicated keys in array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, loops, sorting

I have an array of objects like this. I want to get rid of duplicated keys (name) and only have one name with all of it's related values in an array.

```
let array = [ 
  { name: "dimensions", value: "dimensions value 1" },
  { name: "weight",     value: "weight value 1" },
  { name: "dimensions", value: "dimensions value 2" },
  { name: "weight",     value: "weight value 3" },
  { name: "dimensions", value: "dimensions value 3" },
  { name: "weight",     value: "weight value 3" } 
]
```

I want to turn it to somthing like this :

```
result = [ {
  name : "dimensions", 
  values : ["dimention value 1", "dimention value 2", "dimention value 3"] 
    }, {
  name : "weights", 
  values : ["weight value 1", "weight value 2", "weight value 3"] 
} ]
```

NOTE: The count of the objects in array is variable. "Weight", "Dimensions", "Colors", "Brands", etc ...

what I've tried so far :

```
let flags = [], output = [], l = array.length;

for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    if (flags[array[i].name])
      continue;

    flags[array[i].name] = array[i].name;

    output.push({
        name : array[i].name,
        values : [array[i].value]
    });
}
```

And it returns something like this :

```
[
  { name: "dimensions", values: [ "dimensions value 1"] },
  { name: "weight",     values: [ "weight value 1"] }
]
```

```js
let array = [
  { name: "dimensions", value: "dimensions value 1" },
  { name: "weight",     value: "weight value 1"},
  { name: "dimensions", value: "dimensions value 2"},
  { name: "weight",     value: "weight value 3"},
  { name: "dimensions", value: "dimensions value 3"},
  { name: "weight",     value: "weight value 3" }
]

let flags = [], output = [], l = array.length;

for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  if (flags[array[i].name])
    continue;

  flags[array[i].name] = array[i].name;

  output.push({
    name: array[i].name,
    values: [array[i].value]
  });
}

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` with `Object.values()` to group your array based on `name`.

```js
let array = [ {name: "dimensions", value: "dimensions value 1"}, {name: "weight", value: "weight value 1"}, {name: "dimensions", value: "dimensions value 2"}, {name: "weight", value: "weight value 3"}, {name: "dimensions", value: "dimensions value 3"},{name: "weight", value: "weight value 3"} ],
  result = Object.values(array.reduce((r,{name, value}) => {
    r[name] = r[name] || {name, values : []};
    r[name].values.push(value);
    return r;
  },{}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use ES6 `Map` to store values and then use spread syntax `...` to get values in a array of objects.

```js
let array = [ {name: "dimensions", value: "dimensions value 1"},{name: "weight", value: "weight value 1"},{name: "dimensions", value: "dimensions value 2"},{name: "weight", value: "weight value 3"},{name: "dimensions", value: "dimensions value 3"},{name: "weight", value: "weight value 3"} ]

const map = array.reduce((r, {name, value}) => {
  if(!r.has(name)) r.set(name, {name, values: [value]});
  else r.get(name).values.push(value)
  return r;
}, new Map);

const result = [...map.values()];
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers have produced the output you want you *might* find it easier to work with an object where the keys are "dimensions" and "weights" and their values are the arrays of strings. You can do that with a slightly simpler `reduce`:

```
const out = array.reduce((p, c) => {
  p[c.name] = p[c.name] || [];
  p[c.name].push(c.value);
  return p;
}, {});
```

OUTPUT

```
{
  "dimensions": [
    "dimensions value 1",
    "dimensions value 2",
    "dimensions value 3"
  ],
  "weight": [
    "weight value 1",
    "weight value 3",
    "weight value 3"
  ]
}
```

It just means you can now access the properties:

```
out.dimensions[0]
```

instead of

```
out[0].values
```

which is less less useful imo.